# Online OOP Test: python/nose2/bin/nose2: not found

Tags: python, oop

I am currently taking some programming test over at `http://proctor.andela.com/`and my code for the OOP question works fine /correctly in pyCharm and Idle but while 'testing' the code in the provided editor, I keep getting this error

> /bin/sh: 1: python/nose2/bin/nose2: not found

Therefore I can't submit my code.

I have tried the following:

1. Logged out and back into the curriculum page- No change.
2. Changed my internet to a faster/more reliable one(Saw a post somewhere to make sure the internet connection was stable-I use a 3G connection that  is flaky at times)- No change.
3. Re-wrote my code- No change.

Further research indicates this is brought about by the unittest used to evaluate the code, Does this mean this is a server issue?

I will appreciate any way forward on this matter, as the test are timebound.

**EDIT/ADDITIONAL INFO**
Moved on to another Lab and still getting same error. Does'nt this point to an environment configuration error, or server side error?

My Current setup is:

> Linux Mint 17.3 64 bit.
>   Taking test through Google Chrome as suggested. Same error comes up when I use Firefox.

My code, for reference:

```
class BankAccount(object):

    def deposit(self):
       pass
    def withdraw(self):
       pass

class SavingsAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self):
       self.balance = 500

    def deposit(self, amount):
        if amount < 0:
           return 'Invalid deposit amount'
        else:
           self.balance += amount
           return self.balance
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if amount < 0:
           return 'Invalid withdraw amount'

        elif amount > self.balance:
           return 'Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance'

        elif (self.balance - amount < 500):
           return 'Cannot withdraw beyond the minimum account balance'

        else:
           self.balance -= amount
           return self.balance

class CurrentAccount(BankAccount):

    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 0
    def deposit(self, amount):
        if amount < 0:
            return 'Invalid deposit amount'
        else:
            self.balance += amount
            return self.balance
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if amount < 0:
            return 'Invalid withdrawal amount'
        elif amount > self.balance:
            return 'Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance'
        else:
            self.balance -= amount
            return self.balance
```

**FINAL EDIT & CLOSE**
It was confirmed(by Andela) that indeed the testing platform had serious issues that resulted into it being taken offline for maintenance. I can therefore close this question by confirming that it was a server side issue. Thank you all who replied/commented.

Comment: i just found out that there are hidden tests in this exam. i am stuck there too, kindly assist me with your email tuone vile tunasaidiana...

Comment: @SirGeorge, talking of the hidden tests, I have looked at the unittest, and nothing points towards raising my/our specific error: **/bin/sh: 1: python/nose2/bin/nose2: not found**. I am also wondering how to specifically implement this requirement in __init__ **This constructor sets a property called balance to 500. (This should be the minimum balance at any given time).** Any idea if this could contirbute towards the error?

Comment: give me your email..i am also facing the same problem...avoid talking about it here

Comment: i cant post the error here men its too long..perhaps it might guide us...HERE IS AN ERROR/BUG IN YOUR CODE
Results: 
{"finished": true, "success": [{"fullName": "test_current_account_can_withdraw_valid_cash_amounts", "passedSpecNumber": 1}, {"fullName": "test_current_account_is_instance_of_bank_account", "passedSpecNumber": 2}, {"fullName": "test_savings_account_can_withdraw_valid_amounts_successfully", "passedSpecNumber": 3}, {"fullName": "test_savings_account_is_instance_of_bank_account", "passedSpecNumber": 4}],

Comment: are you selling your email or what??

Comment: I am not about to post my email address to an open forum. If you have no such qualms, post your and I shall get back to you.

Comment: g.okiri79@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All tests are returning the error `/bin/sh: 1: python/nose2/bin/nose2: not found.`
I guess it has to do with Those guys Side. All codes can't have the same error I guess

Comment: Just tried now(09:46 am) and issue remains. I believe it to be a server side issue too, and hope someone over there is working to resolve the same. Everyone to keep checking and report back if its resolved.

Comment: @Chanticleer for example, if you check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240884/an-income-tax-program-in-python  reply he has a final code which he successfully submits 18 days ago but currently cannot be submitted

Comment: Good News. The Guys Replyed to Me.                                                                                             Dear Esir,

We are currently experiencing downtime on our servers. Allow us to resolve the issue then you can try again.

Thanks

Comment: Ah, excellent. Was tiresome looking for hidden tests to satisfy, while it was a server issue. All good, still got some days to go, home its sorted in a few hours. Good job getting the response from them, @Esir Kings.

Comment: @Chanticleer hope you  Accept My Answer then :)

Comment: Have you been able to make any headway?

Answer (score 0):

ok then: look at the test.spy code look at it very carefully for it has got alot to do with the solution..
i found this error :

```
HERE IS AN ERROR/BUG IN YOUR CODE
Results: 
{"finished": true, "success": [{"fullName": 

"test_current_account_can_withdraw_valid_cash_amounts", "passedSpecNumber": 1}, {"fullName": "test_current_account_is_instance_of_bank_account", "passedSpecNumber": 2}, {"fullName": "test_savings_account_can_withdraw_valid_amounts_successfully", "passedSpecNumber": 3},
 {"fullName": "test_savings_account_is_instance_of_bank_account", "passedSpecNumber": 4}], "passed": false, "started": true, "failures": [{"failedSpecNumber": 1, "fullName": "test_current_account_can_deposit_valid_amounts", "failedExpectations": [{"message": "Failure in line 20, in test_current_account_can_deposit_valid_amounts\n    self.assertEquals(balance, 1500)\nAssertionError: None != 1500\n"}]}, {"failedSpecNumber": 2, "fullName": "test_current_account_cannot_withdraw_more_than_current_balance", "failedExpectations": [{"message": "Failure in line 24, in test_current_account_cannot_withdraw_more_than_current_balance\n    self.assertEquals(message, 'Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance', msg='No overdrafts')\nAssertionError: No overdrafts\n"}]},
 {"failedSpecNumber": 3, "fullName": "test_savings_account_can_deposit_valid_amounts", "failedExpectations": [{"message": "Failure in line 44, in test_savings_account_can_deposit_valid_amounts\n 
   self.assertEquals(balance, (1500 + init_balance)
, msg='Balance does not match deposit')\nAssertionError: Balance does not match deposit\n"}]}, {"failedSpecNumber": 4, "fullName": "test_savings_account_cannot_withdraw_more_than_current_balance", "failedExpectations": [{"message": "Failure in line 48, in test_savings_account_cannot_withdraw_more_than_current_balance\n    self.assertEquals(message, 'Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance', msg='No overdrafts')\nAssertionError: No overdrafts\n"}]}], "specs": {"count": 8, "pendingCount": 0, "time": "0.016354"}}
```

this shoul tell you that you have certain things to prove/test..

Comment: Am currently not getting these debug errors, because I revised my code to address all test cases. I am only getting this error code, with no additional details. **THERE IS AN ERROR/BUG IN YOUR CODE
Results: 
/bin/sh: 1: python/nose2/bin/nose2: not found**. This is the particular error this question is about.

Comment: lol thats why you are still stuck there....IF THEY WANTED YOU TO SOLVE THE QUESTION THEN EVERYONE WOULD HAVE, i am trying to tell you there is a hidden test, you need a different approach to this bro..your code  approach will never work, its so obviuos and direct...

Comment: So, what hidden test is my code failing, so as to generate the error I am getting(**/bin/sh: 1: python/nose2/bin/nose2: not found.**)? Which line of my proposed solution to edit/revise? Kindly enlighten me on this 'different approach' that I need to take.

Answer (score 0):

No hidden test.
The unittest is supposed to import the class and it doesnt .
try copying the test and place import class and then run the unittest most likely your code will return ok in another environment.
THIS IS FRUSTRATINGLY UNFAIR

Comment: Hey @Kiki, made any progress regarding the Labs?

Comment: Hi@Chanticleer, I havent made any progress. Been trying hourly tho. Truthfully i doubt it will be resolved before the deadline. We can do either of two things: finish up the quiz and go home or just quit here and now  go home.   I cant go and come and kill myself

Comment: Same here, keep trying every few hours, same thing. Will just therefore watch the deadline slide by...